# Finding the physical page number of a particular logical page

Tags: page-numbering

I need to fetch some part from a pdf file (e.g. with [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/)). The page numbers as given in the table of contents are logical numbers (for example Roman numbers I to XX in the front-matter, main-matter starting with Arabic 1, although being the 21st physical page). Can I get physical numbers of pages for a particular part of a generated document (section, subsection, paragraph...)?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. Could you expand a little on what you want, and explain what you have tried to do so far?

Comment: I have pdf, which was got from pdflatex and name of toc record, I need know what phisical pages this part (under this record) ocсupy and fetch this pages from pdf programmatically (with pdftk, for example). But there are logical (relative) numders of pages in toc file, while I need absolute in all document. Is there any way to know this?

Comment: You want to fetch the physical page numbers corresponding to specific logical page numbers that appear in the toc? For every page? for particular pages?

Comment: yes, exactly. For particular sections, subsection..

Comment: "For the logical page numbers display of the pdf file use logical page numbers together with hyperref!
- In Adobe Reader X enable: Edit > Preferences (Ctrl+k) > Page Display > Page Content and Information > Use logical page numbers .
- Use the hyperref package with option plainpages=false .
The display will be e.g. `7 (7 of 9)`, or, in case of Roman instead of arabic numbers, `VII (7 of 9)`, and when different page numbers are used [...] e.g. arabic after 10 Roman pages: `17 (27 of 30)`. Please try this with the compiled pageslts-example file!" (to be continued)...

Comment: I am sorry that i have not been precise enough. Thanks Stephen for correcting me

Comment: (continuation) ...  (page 4 of [pageslts manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pageslts/pageslts.pdf))
I was so free as to edit your question and hope it is easier to understand now. (Hope that is OK for you.)

Comment: +1 for the question, because in my comment you only get a manual solution, and depending on how the pdf file was created it might not work. If you create the pdf yourself from tex, the [selectp](http://ctan.org/pkg/selectp) package could be of help.

Comment: Thanks, Stepehn. I was not heard about those packages. I will try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A) The get the "physical" number of a page of a PDF document, there are different possibilities, for example:

- manual counting (of course; might be cumbersome as well as prone to errors)
- using Adobe Reader to show also the physical page number: 
  "For the logical page numbers display of the pdf file use logical page numbers together with hyperref! - In Adobe Reader X enable: `Edit > Preferences (Ctrl+k) > Page Display > Page Content and Information > Use logical page numbers`. - Use the hyperref package with option plainpages=false . The display will be e.g. `7 (7 of 9)`, or, in case of Roman instead of arabic numbers, `VII (7 of 9)`, and when different page numbers are used [...] e.g. arabic after 10 Roman pages: `17 (27 of 30)`. Please try this with the compiled pageslts-example file!" (page 4 of [pageslts](http://ctan.org/pkg/pageslts) manual)
- using the [pageslts](http://ctan.org/pkg/pageslts) package to print the physical page number (`\theCurrentPage`) in the footer:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}

  \usepackage{pageslts}

  \makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\@evenfoot}{%
      \hspace*{\fill}%
      Page \thepage\ (\theCurrentPage\ of \lastpageref{LastPages})%
      \hspace*{\fill}%
     }
    \renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{\@evenfoot}
  \makeatother

  \begin{document}
  \pagenumbering{roman}
  Test
  \newpage
  More test text.
  \newpage
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  Now look at the first number in the parentheses in the footer!

  \end{document}
  ```

  This will need at least two compiler runs. When you have determined the page numbers you are looking for, you can just remove the code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` and recompile.

B) "I need to fetch some part from a pdf file". For this you do not necessarily need to know the physical page numbers. For example you could use the [selectp](http://ctan.org/pkg/selectp) package. For example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{selectp}
\outputonly{1,0,1}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
Test
\newpage
More test text.
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
Still more text.

\end{document}
```

will allow only pages i (1; 1 of 3) and 1 (3 of 3) to be output. The order is not random but must be the order that the pages are produced; normally this means the numbers must always increase.

With roman numbers: 1-3, 1-3 prints the pages i-iii, 1-3

and 0, 1-3 prints the pages 1-3.

It needs a complete compiled file before use! (And you must translate e.g. i to 1, but that should not be an issue.)

Comment: Unfortunately `pageslts` seems to be incompatible with [`chappg`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chappg), which allows for page numbers being prefixed with a chapter number... See also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281173/430)

Answer (score 1):

Just a few lines to complete Stephen's answer for people using the memoir class:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english, final]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pageslts}

\makeevenfoot{ruled}{}{}{Page \thepage\ (\theCurrentPage\ of \lastpageref{LastPages})}
\makeoddfoot{ruled}{Page \thepage\ (\theCurrentPage\ of \lastpageref{LastPages})}{}{}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{}{}{Page \thepage\ (\theCurrentPage\ of \lastpageref{LastPages})}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{Page \thepage\ (\theCurrentPage\ of \lastpageref{LastPages})}{}{}
\makeevenfoot{empty}{}{}{Page \thepage\ (\theCurrentPage\ of \lastpageref{LastPages})}
\makeoddfoot{empty}{Page \thepage\ (\theCurrentPage\ of \lastpageref{LastPages})}{}{}

\title{This is a test document}
\author{Myself}

%------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{ruled}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\section{First section}
\lipsum
\section{Second section}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Because you reset the foot for all styles, it will be changed on all pages (even for chapter and title pages).

Comment: Good to know this, thanks for adding it. +1!