# How to check for odd/even pages when numbering pages by chapter?

Tags: page-numbering

As described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212508/430) I'm using [`chappg`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chappg)'s `\pagenumbering{bychapter}` (implicitly via the `auto` option) to have pages numbered in the style `\thechapter-\thepage`. But now a `\ifodd\thepage` fails horribly, as this MWE shows:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}  % same for book, btw
\usepackage[auto]{chappg}

\newcommand*{\whereami}{%
    \ifodd\thepage%
        odd page
    \else
        even page
    \fi
}

\begin{document}
  \whereami\clearpage\whereami

  \chapter{new}
  \whereami\clearpage\whereami

  \chapter{again}
  \whereami\clearpage\whereami
\end{document}
```

While the first two pages (outside a chapter) correctly output "odd page" and "even page" respectively, the first actual chapter yields "-1odd page" and "-2odd page" for its two pages, and the second one "even page" twice.

So it seems `chappg` overrides `\thepage` to become e.g. `1-2`, and `\ifodd\thepage` only checks the chapter number's oddness, in which case the `-2` becomes part of the `then` output.

I already tried fixing this by using [`pageslts`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pageslts)'s `\theCurrentPage` instead, but unfortunately that seems to mess around with `\thepage` (or `\pagenumbering`?) as well, since by merely including that package in addition I get the error

```
! Argument of \extract@ has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.18   \whereami\clearpage
                          \whereami
```

So, how can I fix this mess?

Comment: Isn't this kind of a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6143/if-then-else-for-odd-page-even-page

Comment: @clemens That shows how to get that page numbering style, not why my flawed `\ifodd\thepage` failed

Comment: That's why I said “kind of” and haven't voted to close (BTW: the answers here so far do the same: they show how to get the correct numbering and not where your error is). Since your question is: “how can I fix this mess?” the other question might still be a duplicate…

Comment: Indeed - I wouldn't mind learning _why_ `\ifodd\thepage` is a bad idea - though it probably boils down to "`\thepage` is the page number _label_, not the actual number"

Comment: ...and neither would I mind still knowing how to obtain the absolute page number, which `pageslts` apparently can't when using `chappg`.

Comment: You are right that `\thepage` is not a fixed quantity until page shipout.  Thus, testing upon it can lead to spurious results.

Comment: `\thepage` is indeed wrong for testing the page number since `\thepage` might very well be `\roman{page}` or something, i.e., it does not have to expand to a number so testing for `\value{page}` would be better. But this is only a secondary problem. @StevenB.Segletes mentions the real problem: page numbers are only fixed when the page is shipped out – this is the reason for the various ways for checking even/odd pages which in the end all fetch the information from the aux file.

Comment: Good points by both of you - though at least in a [`\AtBeginShipout`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi) one should have a fixed page number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use KOMA's `\ifthispageodd` instead:

```
\newcommand*{\whereami}{%
    \ifthispageodd{%
        odd page
    }{%
        even page
    }%
}
```

You are not required to use a KOMA script class, you can also just `\usepackage{scrextend}`.

See also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6143/430).

Answer (score 2):

The `changepage` package could be of use.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}  % same for book, btw

\usepackage{changepage}

\newcommand\whereami{\checkoddpage\ifoddpage odd\else even\fi}

\begin{document}
  \whereami\clearpage\whereami

  \chapter{new}
  \whereami\clearpage\whereami

  \chapter{again}
  \whereami\clearpage\whereami
\end{document}
```

Comment: This one doesn't depend on KOMA, which is potentially good (though one can still use `\usepackage{scrextend}` without a KOMA class). On the other hand, I'll most certainly forget to put the `\checkoddpage` in place...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zref` for this, see [this answer by Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24237/4427):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}  % same for book, btw
\usepackage[auto]{chappg}
\usepackage[user,abspage]{zref}

\newcounter{whereami}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\whereami}{%
  \refstepcounter{whereami}%
  \zlabel{\thewhereami @zref}%
    \ifodd\zref@extractdefault{\thewhereami @zref}{abspage}{0}\relax
        odd page
    \else
        even page
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \whereami\clearpage\whereami

  \chapter{new}
  \whereami\clearpage\whereami

  \chapter{again}
  \whereami\clearpage\whereami
\end{document}
```

Of course this needs multiple passes, but using the aux file is the only reliable method for checking page numbers.

Answer (score 1):

> I already tried fixing this by using pageslts's `\theCurrentPage`
>   instead, but unfortunately that seems to mess around with `\thepage` (or
>   `\pagenumbering`?) as well, since by merely including that package in
>   addition I get the error

After adding `\usepackage{pageslts}` and `\pagenumbering{arabic}` before `\usepackage[auto]{chappg}` and replacing `\thepage` with `\theCurrentPage`, i.e.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}  % same for book, btw
\usepackage{pageslts}% <- changed
\pagenumbering{arabic}% <- changed
\usepackage[auto]{chappg}


\newcommand*{\whereami}{%
    \ifodd\theCurrentPage% <- changed
        odd page
    \else
        even page
    \fi
}

\begin{document}
  \whereami\clearpage\whereami

  \chapter{new}
  \whereami\clearpage\whereami

  \chapter{again}
  \whereami\clearpage\whereami
\end{document}
```

I do not have any problem compiling your MWE (current TeXLive 2015). Did you use another order of loading perhaps (or older versions of scrbook/pageslts/chappg)?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure, but I _think_ the problem was that I have a preamble, and `\mainmatter` implicitly does `\pagenumberung{arabic}` which overrides `chappg`'s style then - so my MWE is too minimal...